# Join MySQL tables in ruby on rails 2.3.3 only if all rows from one table are in another table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2, ruby-2.3

I need to select all rows from table Client where Service has all certificates the Client needs.

```
Client
client_id

Service
service_id

Certificate
certificate_id

ClienCertificate
client_id / certificate_id
1           2 
2           3
3           2
3           3

ServiceCertificate
service_id / certificate_id
1           2 
1           3
2           2
3           4
```

If I'm service with id = 1 I should see all 3 clients since I have all the certificates they ask for. If I'm service with id = 2 I should see only client 2 (not client 3 since I'm missing certificate 3), and if I'm service with id = 3 I would see an empty response.

This is what I have so far

```
@clients = Client.all()
.joins(:client_certificates)
.joins(:service_certificates)
.order(:created_at)
.group("client_id");
```

But of course, this selects all clients even if the service only has 1 of all the certificates the clients is asking for. How could I only select when the service has all the certificates the client wants (service can have more certificates that the client needs)

Comment: this statement is confusing 

If I'm service with id = 2 I should see only client 2 (not client 3 since I'm missing certificate 3). 

Ideally for service_id = 2 it should return client_id 1 & 3. Can you pls elaborate?

Comment: Yes, I am trying only to get the clients that I have ALL the certificates they have on table ClientCertificates, and since service 2 only has certficicate_id = 2 on ServiceCertificate, I don't want it to show, because I (as Service) don't have all the certificates the client has

Comment: Can you add the expected output of the query?